# Meaning of いいだけの話だ

Tags: meaning

Sentence:

叩き潰せばいいだけの話だ。

From my understanding, this sentence is composed of:

叩き潰せば - conditional form of 叩き潰す

いい - Good

So I think that 叩き潰せば + いい would translate to something along the lines of: *would be good/nice if you smash it up/defeat it*

But my main problem is with the second half, だけの話だ.

だけ - only

話 - talk

だけの話 - *only talk?*

I can't provide more context to this sentence since I found it as an example of the usage of 叩き潰す, but can someone explain to me the meaning of だけの話だ?

Comment: Not posting as answer because I'm unsure how to explain it but it feels like 'Basically, we just gotta smash it' or 'The point is, we just gotta smash it' to me

Comment: Have you considered 話{はなし} as a noun? Not the verb "to talk," but as a noun something like "the perspective," "the way we put this," analogous to 説法？

Answer (score 2):

The free translation would be "It's easy for us to defeat him completely". だけの話 is translated as "It's a mere thing" and 話 here has nothing to do with talk. It describes an event instead.